# CSS - Change text color depending on background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple layout consisting of three full height divs and a fixed header bar.

```css
body,html {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.header {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  color:white;
  margin:20px;
}

.section1 {
  background:black;
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color:white;
}

.section2 {
  background:white;
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section3 {
  background:black;
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Header Content
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section1">
    Section One Content
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    Section Two Content
  </div>
  <div class="section3">
    Section Three Content
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the header bar text colour change to black when it rolls over the section with the white background.

I have seen a couple of jQuery plugins which should work to achieve this but I am trying to avoid any unnecessary scripts.

Would the CSS `mix-blend-mode` function allow me to achieve this? Does anybody have an example they can point me to of something similar being achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`mix-blend-mode:difference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  color:#fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3{
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.section2 {
  background: white;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Header Content
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section1">
    Section One Content
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    Section Two Content
  </div>
  <div class="section3">
    Section Three Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth noting that IE and Edge doesn't currently support this so you'll require a fallback of some kind if you want this to work in those browsers.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes it's not a surprise, such things never and will never work on IE and edge and honestly I don't care ... if you want to use IE or Edge then don't use fancy things or make things complicated with JS

Comment: It's not a surprise but it is necessary to consider given the users visiting the site may use those browsers.

Comment: According this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613896/how-to-hack-unsupported-mix-blend-mode-css-property the OP can use some diffrentt `color`(as:`grey` and ect) if `mix-blend-mode` not support in browser

Comment: Thanks all, perfect example and super simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery, when something happens, do:

```
$('yourdiv1').css({"color": "black"})
$('yourdiv2').css({"background-color": "white"})
```

To set it to default just:

```
$('yourdiv1').css({"color": ""})
$('yourdiv2').css({"background-color": ""})
```

Also add [transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) to make it look really nice.